# How to combine two JSON strings for storage in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have the following data that really should be one JSON string however I am not sure to combine the two into a valid JSON string. I think lack of sleep is making me not think properly.

{"0":{"a":"22","b":"44","b":"77"}}
{"1":{"a":"2200","b":"4400","c":"7700"}}

I really want it to be something like:

{"0":{"a":"22","b":"44","b":"77"}, "1":{"a":"2200","b":"4400","c":"7700"}} (i am assuming this is a valid JSON string

Comment: Yes, I think you are right. Wouldn't it be better to fix the output at the publisher rather than trying to fix it at the consumer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/4S2wC/ should be what you're looking for, if I understand your question correctly

Comment: wow thanks for taking the time to do that. I truly appreciate the quick response.

Comment: While it's great to post an example, what happens if, go forbid, jsfiddle.net goes offline? Please post your code here as well.

Comment: Well, it is an example of Step 2 of what I suggested.

Answer (score 3):

1. Convert both strings to objects
2. Use `for (var foo in bar)` to loop over all the properties of one object, and copy to the other object
3. Convert back to a string

Answer (score 1):

You could try a regex such as:

```
mystring.replace(/}}\s*{/g,"},");
```

This makes some assumptions around the depth of the object graph and the syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Below function is helps to combine the json object.

```
C#:
        public String toJSONCombine(JSONObject outer, int HVal, int Aval , int Bval , int Cval)
        {    
             JSONObject inner = new JSONObject();
             try {
              inner.put("a", Aval);
              inner.put("b", Bval);
              inner.put("C", Cval);
              outer.put(HVal, inner);
             } 
             catch (JSONException ex) {
               ex.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
```

You can form the json string like that at end

```
{"0":{"a":"22","b":"44","b":"77"}, "1":{"a":"2200","b":"4400","c":"7700"}}
```

I think you want to js. We can make it same Structure using javascripts..

**Using array instead of JsonObject..**

I hope its help to you

Answer (score 0):

Why people create their own function always, it's really out of my mind.
There are lot's of functions out there for you, why not use those?
Jquery has some really good functions about these, like

`$.extend({},j1,j2)`   http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/

`$.merge( [0,1,2], [2,3,4] )` for array marge http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/

[image]